# how to count how many users and how many comments to each post in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

Here is my comments table:

```
   |id(int) | user_id(int) | post_id(int) | text(char)|
   ----------------------------------------------------
   |        |              |              |           |
```

I want to calculate how many users has comments to each post
and how many comments do every post have.

I've already done the latter one as following:

```
select count(*) from comments group by post_id;
```

but how about the first one? any idea?

Comment: Do you have a users table? And posts table?

Comment: Yes, it's easier.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel just count distinct user_id of the same post_id.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes, i have users table.

Comment: COUNT (DISTINC post_id) wouldn't work, if posts exists without comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How many users has comments to every post**

```
SELECT post_id, count(distinct user_id) as user_count 
FROM comments
GROUP BY post_id
```

This way you are avoiding subqueries.

Comment: This answers: _how many unique users have commented on a post_, not what OP wanted.

Comment: @KamilG. - Seems the correct question is: By how many users each post has been commented?

Comment: yes, it seems so... I edited the answer again changing the word "every" to "each".. I´m waiting for @Charles Bao to confirm the edition...

Comment: "each" is exactly what i mean. sorry for my poor english. @LuisTeijon 's answer is what i want.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel hope you are feeling the same thing I do :)

Answer (score 2):

How many post do exists?

```sql
select count(1) from posts
```

How many posts each user have commented?

```sql
select user_id, count(distinct post_id)
from comments
group by user_id
```

Wich users have commented every post?

```sql
select user_id
from comments
group by user_id
having count(distinct post_id) = (select count(1) from posts)
```

How many users have commented every post?

```sql
select count(1)
from (
    select user_id
    from comments
    group by user_id
    having count(distinct post_id) = (select count(1) from posts)
) sub
```

Answer (score 1):

*Edited answer*

**How many users have commented each post with comments**

```
select post_id, count(distinct user_id) as users_count
from comments
group by post_id
```

*Original answer*

**How many users has comments to every post**

I don't see your posts table so I'll assume it exists.

```
select count(*) AS users_with_comments_to_every_post
from (
  select count(distinct post_id) as count_comments
  from comments
  group by user_id
  ) c
inner join ( select count(*) AS count_posts from posts ) p on 
  c.count_comments = p.count_posts
```

We need the posts table to involve posts that have no comments.

**How many comments do every post have**

```
select post_id, count(*)
from comments
group by post_id
```